# Step by step Assembly of state machine

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, encoder

I need help in creating a layout or circuit for this state machine and instructions on how to put the hardware together. 
It’s a rotary encoder that’s application will be into a gaming controller.. scrolling up will spam a certain button and scrolling down will spam another. The hardware components I currently have are 2 Microcontrollers SN74HC74N and SN74HC00N, 4 resistors and 2 capacitors along with breadboard and cheap mouse for encoder and scroll wheel housing to modify into controller. I can supply data sheets for the 74s but I’ve not clue which pins to solder to what. This diagram has been given to me as a start I believe.The bit generator is the 3 terminal encoder. [image: Bit Generator = Encoder]

Comment: which two microcontrollers do you have?

Comment: the SN74HC74N and SN74HC00N aren't microcontrollers, they are flipflops. You don't need these – you need a single microcontroller with an encoder input. Solves the problem with less effort, lower cost, less potential for analog trouble.

Comment: If however, this is an assignment to you and you MUST use these, then you're not showing the amount of independent thought and own research necessary for us to answer homework-style questions. "I have no clue what to solder to what": hold thy horses! Start slow. You need to understand what your mouse does, and how you'd want to detect the direction of turning from that, first. Then, design a schematic from that understand. Then, layout a circuit from the schematic – especially if you're doing this on breadboard. Then, and only then, soldering comes into play.

Comment: Surprisingly the drawing you have provided has 4 resistors and 2 capacitors.  I am going to go out on a limb here and guess you have 4 10k\$\Omega\$ resistors and 2 0.01 \$\mu C\$ capacitors.  You have to determine what Signal A and Signal E are.  You have 2 D-type flip-flops and 4 2-input NANDs to play with.  We don't do your homework, but will answer questions.